# Why I Can't Access The Array Which Is Inside The JSONArrayRequest

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-volley

I am trying to fetch data from my website and store it in an Array. And I did it successfully but why I can't use the Array from outside the JSONArray Request Method. I want to return the 2d Array from my method but it showing me error. I also tried some other ways but in the end I am not able to get any data from the Arrays inside the JSONArray Request Method.

```
public String[][] QuestionAns(){
    String url = "https://testing.testing/q-bank/QnA.php?category=" + this.subject + "&&STD=" + this.std;

    String[] questions = new String[10];
    String[] options1 = new String[10];
    String[] options2 = new String[10];
    String[] options3 = new String[10];
    String[] options4 = new String[10];
    String[] answers = new String[10];

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.context);

    Toast.makeText(this.context, "Check", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, response -> {
                try {

                    JSONArray questionArr = response.getJSONArray("question");
                    JSONArray option1Arr = response.getJSONArray("option1");
                    JSONArray option2Arr = response.getJSONArray("option2");
                    JSONArray option3Arr = response.getJSONArray("option3");
                    JSONArray option4Arr = response.getJSONArray("option4");
                    JSONArray answerArr = response.getJSONArray("answer");

                    for (int i = 0; i<questionArr.length(); i++){
                        questions[i] = questionArr.getString(i);
                        options1[i] = option1Arr.getString(i);
                        options2[i] = option2Arr.getString(i);
                        options3[i] = option3Arr.getString(i);
                        options4[i] = option4Arr.getString(i);
                        answers[i] = answerArr.getString(i);
                    }

                    String [][] QnA = {questions, options1, options2, options3, options4, answers};

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }, error -> Toast.makeText(context, "Something Went Wrong...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());

    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    return QnA;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use variables defined in inner scope in outer scope. In this case QnA in defined in `response -> {}` lambda, and it's not visible in QuestionAns() method.
Moreover, in lambda you cannot modify outer references (outer variables used in lambda need to be effectively final).

I suggest this.

- In QuestionAns(), define `final List QnA` as list of lists.
- Populate that list inside of response -> {} lambda
- At the end of QuestionAns() method transform that list to your array of arrays and return it.

Comment: I created this List

`final List<String[]> QnA = new ArrayList<>();`

And store the Array Values inside it inside of `response -> {}`
 
`QnA.add(questions);
QnA.add(options1);
QnA.add(options2);
QnA.add(options3);
QnA.add(options4);
QnA.add(answers);`

But it not worked on the outside of the  `response -> {}`

`String [][] returnValue = QnA.toArray(new String[0][0]);`

It gives error (An Empty List).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't access variables defined outside the scope. Also if you declare the `Qna` inside the scope, It will still return an empty array because the request takes some time for response.

In order to get the array, you have to use a method called after the response.

**like**

```
public void QuestionAns() {
     . . .

     for (int i = 0; i<questionArr.length(); i++){
          questions[i] = questionArr.getString(i);
          options1[i] = option1Arr.getString(i);
          options2[i] = option2Arr.getString(i);
          options3[i] = option3Arr.getString(i);
          options4[i] = option4Arr.getString(i);
          answers[i] = answerArr.getString(i);
     }

     String [][] QnA = {questions, options1, options2, options3, options4, answers};
     onResponse(Qna);

     . . .
}

public void onResponse(String [][] QnA)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: It doesn't help me because I am using the method from another Class. And if I do as you suggest then how can I return the 2d array from this External Class. Otherwise your answer is a useful answer. But I already tried that ago. And it not worked for me

Comment: @RatnadeepPaul ok then use an interface and implement the interface in that class call the interface method in onResponse